# Xamarin.iOS Build - LLVM disabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to select LLVM as a compiler option, but it is always disabled.  What conditions cause this setting to enable?

[image]

Comment: **Release** mode configurations will allow you to enable LLVM & Thumb2 options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can only use the LLVM compiler if all 'debug' options are disabled inside your build configuration as it's only available for release builds. There is a bugzilla report on this [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57098).

Also I assume you've looked through the xamarin developer documentation on LLVM that can be found [here.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/compiling_for_different_devices/)

It's worth noting that configuration mode 'appstore' doesn't count as release, it has to actually be the 'release' and only 'release' configuration selected.

Comment: `It's worth noting that configuration mode 'appstore' doesn't count as release, it has to actually be the 'release' and only 'release' configuration selected.` - Is this still true, seems rather stupid to be matching on Name (i.e. `if (configname == "Release")`)